# Reference token generation best practices

Tags: node.js, security, cryptography, access-token, restful-authentication

I implemented JWT tokens for my nodejs project but the demand for revoke tokens made me switch to reference bearer tokens to have complete control over token lifetime. According to my project requirements:

1. Tokens must be reasonably shorter than self-descriptive JWT tokens.
2. There must be some way to ensure tokens are issued by the server (like hs256 verification in JWT) but since there is no payload section in reference tokens, the situation becomes more complex.

What are the best practices to implement a secure, infeasible to guess, reference token?

Answer (score 0):

An opaque token is just a ramdom string, which is mapped in server to a authenticated username. Take a look at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19676/token-based-authentication-securing-the-token

> Such a token is good enough for security as long as an attacker cannot create a valid token with non-negligible probability, a "valid token" being "a token which is in the database of emitted tokens". It is sufficient that token values have length **at least 16 bytes and are produced with a cryptographically strong PRNG**

To reduce the server storage requirements, the token can contain the user name and issue date, and encrypted with a HMAC private key so that the server can verify the authenticity.

The last solution is very close to JWT. With JWT you can also mark invalid tokens using a **blacklist**, store until their expiration time and check it in every request . (Blacklist breaks JWT statelessness because it requires maintaining the state)